# Google Sheets Formula - Lookup Last Instance of Value

Tags: google-sheets

I've been trying to figure out how to lookup the last instance of a value in another spreadsheet based on the value of a specific cell in my current one, then return the value of a specific column.

In other words:
Lookup the last instance of the value from B6 in the current spreadsheet in (spreadsheet_url) column C

Once found, return the value of column E within that row

I've had no luck googling this or even trying to use ChatGPT but I feel like there's an easy way.

Comment: Do share some dummy data and the expected result.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X-M_5OSNE3T_OH4QgQYIb4I94xWBI53BZSWZcT3oKXE/

This should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,importrange("1X-M_5OSNE3T_OH4QgQYIb4I94xWBI53BZSWZcT3oKXE","'Other Spreadsheet (Different URL)'!C:E"),
       xlookup(B6,index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,3),,,-1))
```

- ***Replace the `spreadsheet_ID` in the formula with your `source sheet ID`***

[image]